# Subquery using result from parent query

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE** The pay query is now solved with the help provided in the replies. The answer Strawberry provided is very close.  It just needed to be edited a bit as the WHERE clause has a redundancy and incorrect statement that I provided in my original query. Here is the correct, slightly revised query:

```
SELECT ux.user_id
     , ux.meta_value pay
  FROM wp_um_groups_members m
  Join wp_usermeta ux 
    ON m.user_id1 = ux.user_id
 WHERE ux.meta_key = CONCAT('_um_groups_', m.group_id,'_price')
```

This matches the following data for my 'Pay' field:

```
From up_usermeta:

umeta_id | user_id | meta_key               |    meta_value
===========================================================
622680   | 5989    | _um_groups_47652_price |    500


From wp_um_groups_members:

id   | group_id | user_id1 | user_id2 | status   | role   | invites | time_stamp          | date_joined
===============================================================================================================
187  | 47682    | 5989     | 3        | approved | member | 1       | 2020-02-15 10:59:08 | 2020-02-15 10:59:08
```

I through that in with my original query below, and everything is working.

**Original Post**

I'm sure I'm making this much more difficult than it needs to be.  Below is the flow chart and query.  When I add the 'Pay'subquery, I receive results that are not matched correctly.  If I remove the "Pay" subquery, it works fine (with exception that there is no pay).

[image: flow chart of query]

In the database, I have many entries in wp_usermeta.meta_value such as:
`meta_value = _um_groups_47859_price`

In that example, the number 47859 equals the value of wp_um_groups_members.group_id

So I was hoping to be able to query that exact match using something similar to: `LIKE CONCAT('%', wp_um_groups_members.group_id ,'%')`

That did not seem to work either.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
  wp_um_groups_members.group_id AS ID, wp_posts.post_title AS Gig, Location.Location, Type.`Event Type`, wp_users.display_name AS Player, Date.Date, Pay.Pay
FROM
  wp_um_groups_members
Inner Join wp_posts ON 
  wp_um_groups_members.group_id = wp_posts.ID
Inner Join (SELECT 
  wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS Location
FROM
  wp_postmeta
WHERE
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_location'
) Location ON 
  Location.post_id = wp_posts.ID
Inner Join (SELECT 
  wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS `Event Type`
FROM
  wp_postmeta
WHERE
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_type'
) Type ON 
  Type.post_id = wp_posts.ID
Inner Join wp_users ON 
  wp_users.ID = wp_um_groups_members.user_id1
Inner Join (SELECT 
  wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS Date
FROM
  wp_postmeta
WHERE
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_start'
) Date ON 
  Date.post_id = wp_posts.ID
Inner Join (SELECT 
  wp_usermeta.user_id, wp_usermeta.meta_value AS Pay
FROM
  wp_um_groups_members
Inner Join wp_usermeta ON 
  wp_um_groups_members.user_id1 = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE
  wp_usermeta.meta_key like '%price'
) Pay ON 
  Pay.user_id = wp_users.ID
WHERE
  wp_um_groups_members.status = 'approved'
```

Is there a way to to modify that last Inner Join in order to contain something like: `WHERE
  wp_usermeta.meta_value = '_um_groups_47859_price'` in which 47859 would is wp_um_groups_members.group_id?

Comment: show some sample data, what you want to get, and what you are getting (illustrating what you mean by "results that are not matched correctly")

Comment: do you just want to add a condition `wp_usermeta.meta_value = concat('_um_groups_',wp_um_groups_members.group_id,'_price')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ux.user_id
     , ux.meta_value pay
  FROM wp_um_groups_members m
  Join wp_usermeta ux 
    ON m.user_id1 = ux.user_id
 WHERE ux.meta_key LIKE '%price'
   AND ux.meta_value = CONCAT('_um_groups_', m.group_id,'_price')
```

Incidentally, while there's no performance benefit, when working with an EAV (like wp_postmeta), I prefer this syntax...

```
SELECT post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_um_groups_event_location' THEN meta_value END) location
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_um_groups_event_type' THEN meta_value END) event_type
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_um_groups_event_start' THEN meta_value END) date
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_um_groups_event_type' THEN meta_value END) event_type
  FROM wp_postmeta
 GROUP
     BY post_id
```

(Strictly speaking, this is more akin to using LEFT JOIN than INNER JOIN, as per your example)

Comment: Thanks Strawberry.  This is almost solved.  I noticed that your first query needed a small adjustment (meta_value should be meta_key) in the last line.  I have updated that in with your answer in my question.  Are these meant to be two separate queries?  How can I merge them into 1 query?

Comment: I think I was just copying your query

Comment: Sounds like something I'd do!  LOL!  Everything is working!  Thank you!